# Errors via OpenLog implementation in OpenNTF Domino API show incorrect xpage in Agent field

Tags: xpages

I have setup a REST service via a Rest Service control in my Xpages project. The java class for my customRestService is using the logging to OpenLog that is available in the OpenNTF Domino API. But when I make calls to the REST service via Postman or similar I always get the incorrect (undesired) value in the Agent field in the OpenLog document.

It seems that the value is a taken from another Xpage (including URL paramaters) from another application that "happens to be" in memory on the server.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you mind to show some code?

Comment: it is not that advanced e.g. I address this URL: 'http://server1.acme.org/myapp.nsf/api.xsp/agendasUpcoming?method=' + method; and the referring java class has a try-catch block, in the openlog document as reference (agent) is registered "matter.xsp?unid=A28CEF8BABECD9BDC125862400212AF7&editable=true", this reference is random, could be any "recent" xpage on the server. I assume the XSP lifecycle is never initiated for the api.xsp where the REST service control resides on.

Comment: Which version of ODA is this on? There was a bug in earlier versions where some variables were sessionScoped, resulting in the XPage being the first app updated. I think it was this issue fixed in 2016 https://wiki.openntf.org/display/XOL/6.0.1+Release+M6.1. Fixes in XPages OpenLog Logger were made in ODA at the same time, because I was working on both.

Comment: it is the v10 version we use